# Geometry - Find angle ∠C of a triangle given angle bisector and two segment ratios.

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

In the triangle ABC, one has $∠A = 70^o$.

The point $D$ is chosen on the segment
$AC$ such that the angle bisector $AE$ intersects the segment $BD$ at the point $H$, with the following ratios

$$\dfrac{AH}{HE}=\dfrac 31, \>\>\> \dfrac{BH}{HD}=\dfrac 53.$$

Find the angle $∠C$.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Examine the two ratios as follows,

$$\frac{5}{3}= \frac{BH}{HD} = \frac{\triangle ABE} {\triangle AED} $$

$$=\frac{\frac{BE}{BC}\triangle ABC}{\frac{EC}{BC}\frac{AD}{AC}\triangle ABC}= \frac{BE}{EC}\left(\frac{CD}{AD}+1\right)\tag{1}$$

Similarly,

$$\frac{3}{1} = \frac{AD}{CD}\left(\frac{EC}{BE}+1\right)\tag{2}$$

Combine (1) and (2) to obtain

$$ \frac{BE}{EC} = 1$$

Since AE is the angle bisector, $\triangle ABE$ and $\triangle AEC$ are congruent, and therefore $\triangle ABC$ is an isosceles triangle, which yields,

$$∠C= \frac{1}{2}(180^\circ -70^\circ) = 55^\circ$$

Comment: Since $c = b$ the triangle is isosceles and you can simplify the argument without mentioning sines.

Comment: You're right. Thank. Will simplify

Comment: This argument using ratios is quite nice... I would never have seen this.

Comment: I am getting that AD/CD(1+CE/BE)=3

Comment: Correct, there was a typo eRlier

Answer (score 1):

Since we are only conerning angles, let $Area(ΔAHB) = 15$

Area of triangle = ${1\over2}\,a\,b\,\sin(C)$.
If side b changed to $(b + k\;b) \text{, added area} = k\;\{ {1\over2}\,a\,b\,\sin(C)\}$

$\begin{matrix}
{HD \over BH}={3 \over 5} &→ Area(ΔAHD) = {3 \over 5}(15) = 9 \cr  
{HE \over AH}={1 \over 3} &→Area(ΔEHB) = {1 \over 3}(15) = 5 \cr
&→ Area(ΔEHD) = {1 \over 3}(9) = 3 \cr
\end{matrix}$

Let $k = \large{CE \over BE}$

$\begin{align}
Area(ΔCDE) &= k\;Area(ΔBDE) \cr
&= (k)(5+3)\cr\cr
Area(ΔCDE) &= k\;Area(ΔAEB) - Area(ΔAED) \cr
&= (k)(15+5) - (9+3) \cr\cr
8k &= 20k-12 \cr
k &=1
\end{align}$

This implied $CE=BE,\quad ΔAEB ≅ ΔAEC$
$$∠C = {180° - 70° \over 2} = 55°$$